# How to make UISheetPresentationController prefersGrabberVisible follow light/dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit

In setting `UISheetPresentationController`'s `prefersGrabberVisible` to `true`, our app successfully displays the grabber handle at the top of modal view controllers.

However, the grabber is always in the system light/dark mode, ignoring the `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` setting and ignoring the `UITraitCollection` override.

How do we make the grabber respect the specific view controller's light/dark `UIUserInterfaceStyle` instead of just adhering to device light/dark mode?

Answer (score 1):

`overrideUserInterfaceStyle` for the grabber is overrided by its view that's why setting this property to a view controller (or superview) doesn't help.

Therefore, **you can't control the color of the grabber**.

However, if you really want to change it, you can try to change color of the grabber manually finding it in subviews each time `traitCollectionDidChange(...)` is called